# Question about TM Apostol's Calculus Method of Exhaustion. Exercise 1.1.4 1(a)

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the exercises after the explanation of the Method of Exhaustion in Apostol's Calculus I book. The question of interest is question 1(e) of exercise I 1.4 and it goes thus:

If the ordinate at each $x$ is $ax^2 + c$, calculate the area. For context, below is a figure of the method of exhaustion from the book. The ordinate at each $x$ in this figure is $x^2$. [image: Method of exhaustion with ordinate x²]

Here is my attempt at the problem:
Area of a single rectangle is: $$\frac{b}{n}\cdot\left(a\cdot \left(\frac{kb}{n}\right)^2 + c \right)$$

So the sum $S_n$ of the area of the outer rectangles for $k = 1 ... n$ is 
$$S_n = \frac{b}{n}\left(a\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^2 + c \right) + \frac{b}{n}\left(a \left(\frac{2b}{n}\right)^2 + c \right)+ \cdots + \frac{b}{n}\left(a \left(\frac{nb}{n}\right)^2 + c \right),$$ from which we get 
$$S_n = a\left(\frac{b^3}{n^3}\right)(1^2 + \cdots +n^2) + \left(\frac{b}{n}\right)nc$$

Similarly, for the sum $s_n$ of the inner rectangles, with $k = 1 \ldots (n-1)$ inner rectangles,  we get

$$s_n = a\left(\frac{b^3}{n^3}\right)(1^2 + \cdots +(n-1)^2) +bc-\frac{bc}{n}.$$

Now we know that

$$1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 < \frac{n^3}{3}<1^2 + \cdots + n^2$$
Multiplying the inequality above by $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}$ and adding $bc$, we get the inequality:

$$\frac{ab^3}{n^3}\left[1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2\right] + bc < \frac{ab^3}{3}+bc<\frac{ab^3}{n^3}\left[1^2 + \cdots + n^2\right]+bc$$

From the LHS of the ineq above, we have that

$$\left[\frac{ab^3}{n^3}\left[1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2\right] + bc - \frac{bc}{n}\right] < \left[\frac{ab^3}{n^3}\left[1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2\right] + bc \right] < \left[\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc\right]\ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

And so we have that 
$$\left[\frac{ab^3}{n^3}\left[1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2\right] + bc - \frac{bc}{n}\right] < \left[\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc\right] < \left[\frac{ab^3}{n^3}\left[1^2 + \cdots + n^2\right]+bc\right]$$

i.e we have that $$s_n < \left[\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc\right] < S_n$$.

Now the rest of the proof is to show that $\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc$ is the ONLY number between $s_n$ and $S_n$, i.e if A is a number such that $s_n<A<S_n$, then $$A = \frac{ab^3}{3}+bc$$ And this can easily be shown using law of trichotomy and contradiction to show that $A > \frac{ab^3}{3}+bc$ and $A < \frac{ab^3}{3}+bc$ are both FALSE, hence $A = \frac{ab^3}{3}+bc$. I won't post that here for brevity.

**My confusion is then:** If we are able to show that $\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc$ is the only number between $s_n$ and $S_n$, what about the number

$$\frac{ab^3}{n^3}\left[1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2\right] + bc$$

from equation (*) above which is obviously between $s_n$ and $S_n$?

Am I doing something wrong with my attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
A_n:= \frac{ab^3}{n^3}[1^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2] + bc.
$$
Then it is true that
$$
s_n < A_n < S_n,
$$
but $A_n$ depends on $n$. It isn't a unique number, contrary to
$$
\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc.
$$
You may notice that, as expected,
$$
A_n \to \frac{ab^3}{3}+bc \,\,\,\,\,\, (n \to \infty)
$$